# Flask cant access to any COM

Tags: python, flask, arduino, pyserial

I need to develop a website that controlls a dc motor with arduino using flask.

I have this HTML.-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Control de Motor</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Control de Motor</h1>
    <button id="btn-antihorario">Sentido Antihorario</button>
    <button id="btn-pausa">Pausa</button>
    <button id="btn-horario">Sentido Horario</button>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#btn-antihorario").click(function() {
                $.get("/antihorario");
            });

            $("#btn-pausa").click(function() {
            $.get("/pausa");
            });

            $("#btn-horario").click(function() {
                $.get("/horario");
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html
```

This is my python code.------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import serial

app = Flask(__name__)
arduino = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600)  

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/antihorario')
def antihorario():
    arduino.write(b'a') 
    return "Sentido Antihorario"

@app.route('/pausa')
def pausa():
    arduino.write(b'p')  
    return "Pausa"

@app.route('/horario')
def horario():
    arduino.write(b'h') 
    return "Sentido Horario"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The problem is when i try to debbug python i receive the next error---------------------------------

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial'
  File "C:\Users\ing_l\OneDrive\Escritorio\Motor\app.py", line 5, in <module>
    arduino = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial'
```

---

And when i use cmd to run the program with flask, i got the error "13, access denied, none, 5"

When i write arduino.close() just after arduino = serial.Serial flask is able to run but does nothing because cant find the port and buttons dont work.

Flask is in the most recent version, also python i correctly installed.

The code i provide is just a sketch. Im student and i dont know what i am doing. the code use to work and stopped suddenly for no reason.

I try uninstalling flask, pyserial etc... nothing works i dont know what to do

Comment: Are any of your python scripts named serial.py?

Comment: note `debug=True` causes flask to try to reload the script, this may cause other problems later as this will involve closing and re-opening the serial port ... which may fail.

Comment: @stan61285 no, i dont have it.

Comment: @AhmedAEK should i delete that line?

Comment: Did you maybe install serial (the JSON parser) instead of pyserial (the communications library)?  How did you install the library?

Answer (score 0):

Try to open port in this way:

```
serial.Serial('COM4', 9600, timeout=1)
```

Comment: same error in python :(, serial.Serial